# Running angular2 AOT and getting implicitly errors

Tags: angular, angular-cli

So I am trying out the AOT in angular-cli and am stumped by the following output when I run:

```
node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json
```

Error:

```
> app/service/login.service.ts:14:51: Parameter 'fulfill' implicitly has
> an 'any' type. /app/service/login.service.ts:14:60: Parameter 'reject'
> implicitly has an 'any' app.component.ts:74:5: Member 'isLoggedIn'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Any idea what would cause this and how to fix it?

**Details:**

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0
node: 7.6.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.9
@angular/compiler: 2.4.9
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.9
@angular/core: 2.4.9
@angular/forms: 2.4.9
@angular/http: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-server: 2.4.9
@angular/router: 3.4.9
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0
MacBook-Pro-2:www-fairplay bjnash$ tsc -v
Version 2.2.1Version 2.2.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app/service/login.service.ts:14:51: Parameter 'fulfill' implicitly has
>   an 'any' type. /app/service/login.service.ts:14:60: Parameter 'reject'
>   implicitly has an 'any' app.component.ts:74:5: Member 'isLoggedIn'
>   implicitly has an 'any' type.

Just add a `:any` to those vars.

**login.service.ts** replace `fulfill` declaration to `fulfill: any`, `reject` for `reject: any`.

**app.component.ts** replace `isLoggedIn` declaration for `isLoggedIn: any`.

Also if you want to leave all as you have it, check your **tsconfig-aot.json**

Find this line, it should be set to `false`

```
"noImplicitAny": true
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did not realise I could cast in the actual method: new Promise(function (fulfill:any, reject:any) {